# Сбор всех логов с девайса в приложении

Tags: android, adb, logcat

Проблема: Приложение общается с другими приложениями (нативная камера к примеру) и в какой-то момент сторонее приложение крешится. Так как Crashlitics шлет только свои креши никаких рапортов не видно. Кастомеры не умеют собирать логи через adb. В QA версии приложения я пытаюсь собрать логи таким путем:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "logfile" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".txt");
                String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -f " + path).waitFor();
                Log.i("DEBUG", "LOG: " + path + " . size:" + file.length());
```

но собранные таким образом логи относятся только к процессу связанному с моим приложением в то время как при подключении через USB обычная команда adb shell logcat нам дает логи всех процессов. Есть ли способ собрать логи других процессов используя код изнутри приложения?

Comment: Чтобы читать все логи у приложения должно быть специальное разрешение. Смотрите в [этом ответе engSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37541596/3069565)

Comment: У меня есть это разрешение так как это тестовое приложение для QA, но мне мало всех логов приложения так как падает сторонее приложение. мне нужно все логи девайса, аналогично тому что выдает adb shell logcat с консоли

Comment: Вы смотрели ответ? Там вроде как именно команда `logcat` и выполнятся. Если не указывать фильтры, то должны быть все логи

Comment: Да, похоже это правильный ответ